# Negative coefficients of regressors in arimax,should be positive

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, count-data

I have two years of daily time series inbound call centers data starting from Jan 2018 to Nov 2019.
I am doing arimax and regressors are mainly promotional flag along with day of the week (sun, mon ...) and months taken after one hot encoding
So I have six weekdays and 11 months.

In the series every year in aug and nov, dec there is a peak in incoming call numbers as compared to any other months.

So I was expecting +ve regressors coefficients for the three months but to my surprise all months are having negative coefficients.

[image: image of R arima output]

However if I took only these three months (Aug, Nov and dec) ignoring all other months then it becomes positive which is what it should be.

Can anyone please suggest why the coefficients of these three months are negative?

Comment: You are fitting a fairly complicated model, so surprises really are not ruled out. What impresses me more is that perhaps only one of the terms you mention will show significance at conventional levels. For August and November the ratio of coefficient estimate to its standard error is only moderate. I think you have noisy data (sympathies, but no surprise there) and are fitting an unduly complicated model, although styles and advice on parameterisation do vary even from those with much statistical experience.

Comment: This seems to be count data, so variance is not constant. Maybe try some transformations, or a count data time series model. Also, as noted by Nick Cox, most `month` coefficients are small compared to standard errors, maybe compare with a model without those dummys.

Comment: Are you saying that since the ratio is less so high p value value and therefore these variables are not significant?